# Complexity of differentiation (numeric vs. automatic/algorithmic).

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am reading about automatic differentiation and am wondering what the direct comparison is between the complexity of automatic (algorithmic) differentiation and numerical (finite difference) differentiation.

If we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ whose arithmetic cost of evaluation is $\text{Cost}(f) = C$, and we want to compute the Jacobian matrix $\mathbf{J}$, are the following temporal complexities correct ?

1. Numeric differentiation:

$$
\mathcal{O}(C \cdot n \cdot m)
$$

2. Forward (tangent) mode automatic differentiation:

$$
\mathcal{O}(1) \cdot C \cdot n
$$

2. Reverse (adjoint) mode automatic differentiation:

$$
\mathcal{O}(1) \cdot C \cdot m
$$

I am also interested in the spacial complexities, and have read that the spacial complexity of reverse mode automatic differentiation is proportional to the cost of evaluating the function. However I am yet to find a concise summary of the spacial complexities of the three approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Numerical differentiation has about the same cost as forward differentiation.

Forward AD has more cost, as it has to treat the function as evaluation recipe over some "dual number" data type, where the "imaginary" part of the dual number is a vector. So in some sense it replaces a compiled function with an interpreted function. Source code transformation methods largely eliminate this overhead, but are not as flexible as methods using computational graphs and tapes as actual data structures.

Numerical differentiation has stability issues. If using central differences, the optimal step size is proportional to $\mu^{1/3}$, for instance $h=(1+|x|)\mu^{1/3}$, with relative error of the derivative $\sim \mu^{2/3}$. In contrast, AD has the same error mechanism as direct evaluation, the relative error is proportional to $3M\mu$ where $M$ is the number of elementary operations and function evaluations in the given function, so that $M\mu$ is an estimate of the relative error for the bare function evaluation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'numerical differentiation has about the same cost as forward AD' ? Are the complexities I wrote not correct ?

Comment: Yes, they are not correct. Numerical differentiation requires two function evaluations per basis vector (in central mode, one-sided only one additional evaluation, but with loss of half the digits). You need to compare same to same, in AD the evaluation of the whole vector-valued function is treated as one block with fixed cost, so you need to do the same in the difference quotients.

Comment: Could you please explain what the correct complexities are ? The complexity I presented for finite difference differentiation ($\mathcal{O}(Cnm)$) accounts for the two function evaluations in the numerator from what I can tell.

Comment: You have a function $F:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$. Let $C(F)$ be the cost for one evaluation of $F$. Then the cost for the numerical and forward Jacobian (and the function values) is about $(2n+1)C(F)$ plus the cost for the actual difference quotients in the first case. If the evaluation of $F$ is of $m$ independent and equally expensive functions $f_k$, then $C(F)=mC(f_k)$. Similarly if $F$ contains matrix-vector multiplications there can result a factor $mn$. But usually the computational graph of $F$ will be more sparse and lean.

Comment: Would that not be $\mathcal{O}(C(F_k) \cdot m \cdot n)$ ?

Comment: Weak "No", the differentiation is not really much more than the multiple evaluation of $F$ or its AD modification. All the detail cost is in the no further specified $C()$. You could make an argument  for $O(L(F)⋅n)$ or $O(L(F_k)⋅m⋅n)$ where $L(F)$ is the size, here node count, of the computational graph for the evaluation of $F$.